# Change the display of Global Weather service for rest application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

Im using Global Weather service from webservicex website.

I have a form, where user types in the city, and app returns weather data for that city.

The problem is that content displayed is very funny and i don't know how to change it.

**This is my code**

```
 string url = String.Format("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CountryName=Slovenia&CityName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(city.Text));

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        display.Text = client.DownloadString(url);
```

**This is the Result, when it type in a city**

```
Vreme: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <CurrentWeather> <Location>Maribor /     Slivnica, Slovenia (LJMB) 46-29N 015-41E 265M</Location> <Time>May 20, 2014 - 04:30   PM EDT /   2014.05.20 2030 UTC</Time> <Wind> from the SSW (200 degrees) at 6 MPH (5 KT) (direction variable):0</Wind> <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility> <Temperature> 62 F (17 C)</Temperature> <DewPoint> 48 F (9 C)</DewPoint> <RelativeHumidity> 59%</RelativeHumidity> <Pressure> 30.03 in. Hg (1017 hPa)</Pressure> <Status>Success</Status> </CurrentWeather>
```

Can you please help me change this display into something more normal?

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

**Data displayed should look like that.**

Location: Maribor / Slivnica, Slovenia (LJMB) 46-29N 015-41E 265M

Temperature: 62 F (17 C)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Please look at the post again. It's edited. Forgot to enter the spaces so it didn't show the all the parts

Comment: So it gives you XML back - *your C# code* will have to parse that XML to extract separate values and display them in style you want

Comment: You still dont describe the output you want.  What you are receiving is XML there are a myriad of XML parsers to display the data any way you want.

Comment: @paqogomez im kinda new to this so i don't rly know how to parse it

Comment: I understand that, thats why I'm asking you to edit your question and put in how you want it to look.  What data do you want to display, how do you want to display it?  Stuff like that.

Comment: @paqogomez i edited my post. Display should be done like above, and data displayed should be city, country and temperature

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XML in C# with an `XmlReader` object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I find `XDocument` to be the easiest way to handle XML.

By getting the root, then looking for your elements specifically, the values are not hard to come by.

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);  //use .Load if you are pulling an xml file.
  var location = doc.Root.Element("Location").Value;
  var temp = doc.Root.Element("Temperature").Value;
  Console.Write("Location: {0} {1}Temperature: {2}", 
                 location, Environment.NewLine, temp);
```

### [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAGR3O)

Comment: Can i do it like that?

 string url = String.Format("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CountryName=Slovenia&CityName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mesto.Text));

var doc = XDocument.Load(url);

I need to have string url = string.Format, it says in my assignment. And it's ASP.NET app so i don' think Cnsole.Write is gonna work. And if i use label.text to display it, i get object reference error

Comment: Ok, I output to the console because its easy.  As far as your object reference error goes, that has to do with your instantiating the label, not parsing the xml.

Comment: in your DotNet Fiddle file, this will only show data for city (Maribor). That's why i need to use the service link, so it will display data for whatever city i want to. Thats why i need to use a textbox to input city and label.text to display data

Comment: @user3652303 You are correct, this will only show the one query.  You need to query the global weather service for each city, (user enters a city then hits a button), then parse the xml as I have shown and then set the label appropriately.

Comment: @user3652303 any movement on this?  Were you able to make it work?